# Grouping Regex Output According to Directory Name

Tags: regex, bash, scripting, grep

I was trying to write a bash script in order to apply regex on this file.

```
somedir1/include/log.h:65:inline void ERROR(int, const std::string&)      {}
somedir1/common/packet.cpp:68:        ERROR(1, "File couldn't be opened");
anotherdir2/core/client.cpp:380:    ERROR(error, "Connection error");
otherdir3/src/client.cpp:534:            ERROR(1, "Wrong command");
```

However, I cannot manage to collect the directory names as variable.

Last stable regex material I have is:

```
 [^,]*\/[^,]*:[0-9]*:[^,].*\n
#[^,]--->This one is the one I am interested in.
```

My goal is to group the entries that share the same parent directory in same file. For instance;

```
fileName:   report_somedir1 
content:    somedir1/include/log.h:65:inline void ERROR(int, const std::string&)      {}
content:    somedir1/common/packet.cpp:68:        ERROR(1, "File couldn't be opened");
```

What is the correct way to store the first pattern as a variable?
Thank you in advance, for your time and patience.

Comment: Your desired output doesn't match your sample input.  You will likely get better answers if you make the two fully consistent.

Comment: @John1024 Does it not?

Comment: It does match. fileName and content are to guide people.

Comment: @123 The string `report_somedir1` appears in the output but not in the input.  The string `client.cpp` appears twice in the input but not once in the output.

Comment: report_somedir1 is an example name for the output file. Not the output's itself. Since we grouped them by somedir1, and client.cpp's belong to other directories, we don't see them in this output. How come people share destructive comments without reading @John1024

Comment: @Elesmoth _"How come people share destructive comments"_  Remember that people here are offering to help you _for free_.  Asking for clarification of your requirements is __not__ "destructive."

Comment: If it is a constructive comment I would love to change the mistaken part.

Comment: @Elesmoth You clarified just enough for me to write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
awk -F/ '$1 != d{close(f); d=$1; f="report_"d} {print >>f}' file
```

The above command will result in the creation of three files:

```
$ cat report_somedir1 
somedir1/include/log.h:65:inline void ERROR(int, const std::string&)      {}
somedir1/common/packet.cpp:68:        ERROR(1, "File couldn't be opened");
```

And:

```
$ cat report_anotherdir2 
anotherdir2/core/client.cpp:380:    ERROR(error, "Connection error");
```

And:

```
$ cat report_otherdir3
otherdir3/src/client.cpp:534:            ERROR(1, "Wrong command");
```

#### How it works

- `-F/`

  This sets the field divider to `/`.  In this way, the first field will be the directory.
- `$1 != d{close(f); d=$1; f="report_"d}`

  If the first field of the current line differs from the previous, then close the old file, update the variable `d` and create a new filename `f`.
- `print >>f`

  Print the current line to file `f`.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution.